# Destroying an object on collision

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been trying a way to get rid of an enemy in my game, but once the weapon in the game collides with it it does not do what it's suppose to do. So I tried a different way by turning of the box collider2d, the sprite renderer and another script inside it. But it still does not work.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IM5nw.png)

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: Have you tried removing those things from the component entirely?

Comment: No. Well I don't know how to destroy an object so I just disable it's components.

Comment: Other than destroy is well documented what exactly is not working what happens and how have you debugged what’s going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `Destory` to destroy the `gameObject`

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision) 
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Sword")
        {
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I dont know why but it wont work.

Comment: Does it even gets called? does the code reaches inside the if statement